# Generate new file at every hour in Log4j.xml

Tags: java, log4j

I want to create log file for every hour with new name using log4j. I am using application server as JBoss EAP 6.2. Please help me out how to configure it in log4j.xml.

Comment: Use a [`DailyRollingFilAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html). The name is a misnomer and the roll interface is configurable. Also note that it's quite buggy.

Comment: Can you explain me in detail?

Comment: Your question shows very little research effort. Read the documentation I linked, try and follow it. When you hit an actual issue post your issue with an SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an Appender in jboss-log4j.xml. Use DailyRollingFileAppender with "'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH" date pattern and name conversion as you want.

ex:

```
<appender name="NEW_APPENDER" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/NEW_FILE_NAME.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <!-- Rollover at every hour -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- New name convension -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>
```